# partial packets recieved with scapy and python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, http, scapy

I am trying to sniff long packets, specifically http packets that contain html code.
this is the code I am using:

```
from scapy.all import *

f = open('outHTML.txt','wb')

def packet_callback(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Raw) and pkt[Raw].load:
        if str(pkt[Raw].load).find("<html") != -1:
            f.write(bytes('\n' + "=" * 50 + '\n', encoding = "utf8"))
            f.write(pkt[Raw].load)
            f.flush()

sniff(prn=packet_callback)
```

for some reason when I am sniffing, I don't get all of the code.
for example, I got this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 14:00:57 GMT
Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 14:00:57 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Contenet-Type-Options: nosniff
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: TS01b8cd54=019790ad781b859b67afd842e20f0cefeebdf19683a53ff0c282ad209e1bcd0e8d590944badeef97f3d54ed8ab8c7efc5614812de7b7daaddfa8ce09ddf390077f7d2652ce; Path=/; Domain=.rishuy.mot.gov.il
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

4000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="he-il" lang="he-il" dir="rtl">
<head>


<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


<base href="http://rishuy.mot.gov.il/he/" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="רשיומט, רישוי קול, משרד הרישוי, רישוי נהיגה, רישוי כלי רכב" />
    <meta name="description" content="משרד התחבורה - רשות הרישוי" />
    <title>רשות הרישוי</title>
    <link href="/he/?format=feed&amp;type=rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" />
    <link href="/he/?format=feed&amp;type=atom" rel="alternate" t
```

followed by a  **lot**  of NUL bytes.
(in the website there is html code instead of those NUL bytes).
how do I get the rest of the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sniffing long packets with Scapy and python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314511/sniffing-long-packets-with-scapy-and-python-3)